# ui_metrics in twitter login form

Tags: c#, vb.net, twitter, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm doing some apps which require login into a twitter account using HttpWebRequest.
In the POST request there's a parameter called "ui_metrics", What is this parameter used for? Is there a problem if I didn't send it?
[image]

The content of it is generated by this script:
https://twitter.com/i/js_inst?c_name=ui_metrics

Edit:
I also want to convert this script to C# or VB.NET, I know how to download it to a string, but how to get the value it returns, which is ui_metrics as shown in the above screen.
so, To be clear of what I want:

1. What is this parameter used for?
2. Why this javascript is called 3 times? ( I knew this by monitoring web traffic )
3. Is there a problem if I didn't send it?
4. How to generate the value it returns from the javascript in C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deobfuscate this script, the result I reached is this:

```js
'use strict';
function function_A() {
    var detectIdle = function load() 
    {
        function init() 
        {
            var y2 = 97;
            var y1 = 29;
            var y = 21;
            var res = 254;
            y1 = y1 | res;
            y1 = function(s, name, overrideY) {
                function Rule(dayRule) {
                    this.USghQ = function() {
                    return this.qpGvE ^ dayRule;
                    };
                }
                var undefined = {
                    qpGvE : overrideY
                };
                var rule = new Rule(s);
                rule.qpGvE = name;
                Rule.prototype = undefined;
                return rule.USghQ() | (new Rule(name)).USghQ();
            }
            (y1, y2, y2);
            y = function(namespace, value, data) {
                function get(item, value) {
                    var i = 0;
                    for (; i < 8; i++) {
                        var t = document.createElement("div");
                        item.appendChild(t);
                        t.innerText = value;
                        
                        if ((value & 1) == 0) {
                            item = t;
                        }
                        value = value >> 1;
                    }
                    return item;
                }
                
                function update(element, object, end) {
                    if (!element || element == object) {
                        return end % 256;
                    }
                    for (; element.children.length > 0;) {
                        element.removeChild(element.lastElementChild);
                    }
                    return update(element.parentNode, object, end + parseInt(element.innerText));
                }
                
                var i = document.createElement("div");
                i.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(i);
                var a = update(get(get(get(i, namespace), value), data), i, 0);
                i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
                return a;
            }
            (y, y2, y);
            res = function(s, name, overrideY) {
                function Rule(dayRule) {
                this.AGAog = function() {
                return this.QWVxt ^ dayRule;
                };
                }
                var undefined = {
                QWVxt : overrideY
                };
                var rule = new Rule(s);
                rule.QWVxt = name;
                Rule.prototype = undefined;
                return rule.AGAog() | (new Rule(name)).AGAog();
            }
            (res, y2, y1);
            y1 = ~y1;
            y1 = function(name, s, overrideY) {
                function Rule(dayRule) {
                    this.bjQRh = function() {
                    return this.XMmHE ^ dayRule;
                    };
                }
                var undefined = {
                    XMmHE : overrideY
                };
                var rule = new Rule(name);
                rule.XMmHE = s;
                Rule.prototype = undefined;
                return rule.bjQRh() | (new Rule(s)).bjQRh();
            }
            (y1, res, y2);
            y1 = y1 ^ (new Date(y1 * 10000000000)).getUTCDate();
            y2 = y2 ^ res;
            y2 = ~(y2 & y1);
            y = y | y2;
            y1 = y1 ^ res;
            y1 = function(value, namespace, data) {
                function get(item, value) {
                    var i = 0;
                    for (; i < 8; i++) {
                        var t = document.createElement("div");
                        item.appendChild(t);
                        t.innerText = value;
                        if ((value & 1) == 0) {
                            item = t;
                        }
                        value = value >> 1;
                    }
                    return item;
                }
                function update(element, object, end) {
                if (!element || element == object) {
                return end % 256;
                }
                for (; element.children.length > 0;) {
                element.removeChild(element.lastElementChild);
                }
                return update(element.parentNode, object, end + parseInt(element.innerText));
                }
                var i = document.createElement("div");
                i.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(i);
                var a = update(get(get(get(i, value), namespace), data), i, 0);
                i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
                return a;
            }
            (y1, y, y);
            y = y ^ y1;
            y1 = ~(y1 & y);
            y2 = y2 ^ y2;
            res = function(spec, y, n24) 
            {
                function Date(s) {
                    this.zzqeC = function() {
                        return this.FnqRf ^ s;
                    };
                }
                var original = {
                    FnqRf : n24
                };
                var c = new Date(spec);
                c.FnqRf = y;
                Date.prototype = original;
                return c.zzqeC() | (new Date(y)).zzqeC();
            }
            (res, y1, y);
            y1 = ~y1;
            y = y & res;
            y = ~y;
            y1 = function(name, data, objResponse) {
                function Section(value) {
                this.iGKhJ = function() {
                return this.eCRWB ^ value;
                };
                }
                var _Date_prototype = {
                eCRWB : objResponse
                };
                var section = new Section(name);
                section.eCRWB = data;
                Section.prototype = _Date_prototype;
                return section.iGKhJ() | (new Section(data)).iGKhJ();
            }
            (y1, y, res);
            y1 = y1 ^ (new Date(y1 * 10000000000)).getUTCDate();

            y2 = function(value, namespace, data) 
            {
                function get(item, value) {
                    var i = 0;
                    for (; i < 8; i++) {
                        var t = document.createElement("div");
                        item.appendChild(t);
                        t.innerText = value;
                        if ((value & 1) == 0) {
                            item = t;
                        }
                        value = value >> 1;
                    }
                    return item;
                }
                function update(element, object, end) {
                    if (!element || element == object) {
                    return end % 256;
                    }
                    for (; element.children.length > 0;) {
                        element.removeChild(element.lastElementChild);
                    }
                    return update(element.parentNode, object, end + parseInt(element.innerText));
                }

                var i = document.createElement("div");
                i.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(i);
                var a = update(get(get(get(i, value), namespace), data), i, 0);
                i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
                return a;
            }

            (y2, y, y);
            y2 = function(value, key, status) 
            {
                function get(item, value) {
                    var i = 0;
                    for (; i < 8; i++) {
                        var t = document.createElement("div");
                        item.appendChild(t);
                        t.innerText = value;
                        if ((value & 1) == 0) {
                        item = t;
                        }
                        value = value >> 1;
                    }
                    return item;
                }
                function update(element, object, end) {
                    if (!element || element == object) {
                    return end % 256;
                    }
                    for (; element.children.length > 0;) {
                    element.removeChild(element.lastElementChild);
                    }
                    return update(element.parentNode, object, end + parseInt(element.innerText));
                }
                var i = document.createElement("div");
                i.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(i);
                var a = update(get(get(get(i, value), key), status), i, 0);
                i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
                return a;
            }
            (y2, y1, y1);
            y = y ^ y2;
            res = ~(res & y2);
            res = res & res;
            y2 = y2 ^ y1;
            y1 = ~y1;
            y1 = ~(y1 & y2);
            y2 = function(name, json, overrideY) {
                function Section(value) {
                this.DJrcU = function() {
                return this.OCEGA ^ value;
                };
                }
                var _Date_prototype = {
                OCEGA : overrideY
                };
                var s = new Section(name);
                s.OCEGA = json;
                Section.prototype = _Date_prototype;
                return s.DJrcU() | (new Section(json)).DJrcU();
            }
            (y2, res, y1);
            y1 = y1 ^ (new Date(y1 * 10000000000)).getUTCDate();
            return {
                "rf" : {
                "ac133410c945cc4ec78ca58122a0d846d3b68bf81460c0ccd5d1d63a2573066a" : y2,
                "c4564511aef468a7853ced7853bc4440ce63dad605706f0caab8f2088bed1899" : y1,
                "a01041174f8b8fcc122f49a86656b6d994e61f028f2f39d200be3b408f617a61" : y,
                "a93442d9c7d65cb1bbb21984d5261c7de76c8b3b6bf37c1918059f6f0dfefc58" : res
                },
                "s" : "caeM1pzDfd3B7lRINfvP-_jYwuXsE8WuEk9oRuy1WebhbLM9hGtM7nY6SemooLmlQUtAQDMN6fX1TGBl6C3fcRe_jDgevtWJTLR8MZQYxRNsCdIgHdfEj3nb0rManz0VnQeAhzLD1MWJfMuP3dlxGv3sATF7u6GJd1MKbqZ5JTQnV64Vx_B4s6jio82LhJy3QFmg4S_nHIckJFdCwHsrZa-VcIpwPTSO1pQPOSVV-CXCp89Sos944wXgdBxhh-TFEDUZnoWxDdcZFuN7ATsLC2QSO5PVQEty4BfLuOBq0--85BNcwwPVToI4sgTd7XSVtE3t5nSrrCXQ20KIZ0fjlQAAAXap9JSx"
            };
        }
        var completion;
        try 
        {
            completion = JSON.stringify(init());
        } 
        catch (endQuote) 
        {
            completion = "exception " + endQuote;
        }

        var in_tokens;
        in_tokens = document.getElementsByName("ui_metrics");
        var i = 0;

        for (; i < in_tokens.length; i++) {
            in_tokens[i].value = completion;
        }
    };
    var $__jsx_onload = function $__jsx_onload() {
        document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $__jsx_onload);
        window.removeEventListener("load", $__jsx_onload);
        window.setTimeout(detectIdle);
    };
    if (document.readyState === "complete") 
    {
        window.setTimeout(detectIdle);
    }else 
    {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $__jsx_onload);
        window.addEventListener("load", $__jsx_onload);
    }
}
function_A();
```

Comment: deobfuscating does not answering question itself please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

It is used for calculations and logging of different ui interaction metrics (such as the time it takes to fill the form).
The function you linked to is obfuscated meaning twitter doesn't wants you to know what exactly it does. If you want to get a hint start [here](https://www.javascriptdeobfuscator.com/) and paste the function code.
If you won't send it the request will probably fail(try disabling the ui_metrics in the request params "ui_metrics=off")

Comment: The request doesn't fail, but logging in a lot without this parameters makes twitter suspend account. Does ui_metrics may be a solution for that ?
The deobfuscator doesn't help a lot. It makes the script more readable but still not clear.

Comment: And how to generate the value that the script returns in C# ?
I mean I have downloaded now the script as string, How can I get the ui_metrics from this string in C# ?

Comment: As explained [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/what-is-ui-metrics-in-twitter-login-form/100098/6?u=andypiper) this is not supported and against the Twitter Rules, so that why the account is liable to be suspended if you go down this route. I'd advise you to use the official API instead.

Comment: @AndyPiper As I know, Javascript is client-side programming language, so I think there's some way to do it.